# How to register for push notifications outside the AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I have push notifications already setup and working in the appdelegate but instead of having them launch as soon as the app opens, I want them to launch on a separate "Allow Push Notifications" view controller after the user has signed up for the app. I tried making a reference to the `appDelegate` by doing this:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

I have a `registerForPushNotifications` function in the `appDelegate`:

```
func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
}
```

Which works when called from within the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function in the `AppDelegate` but when I try and call that function on my view controller I don't have anything to pass in for the application part of the function, so I wind up getting an error.

```
@IBAction func yesButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    appDelegate.registerForPushNotifications(application)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("pushToHomeSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have anything to pass in for `application`?

```
appDelegate.registerForPushNotifications(UIApplication.sharedApplication())
```

Comment: I tried that but the alert to receive push notifications doesn't pop up

Comment: @SwiftyJD You probably need to reset your simulator since you've likely already approved it for your app. Go to Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings and run it again.

Comment: That helped, it shows up on that screen now.  In the app I have a switch that you can turn push notifications on and off.  Is there a way to switch the push notifications settings this way?

Comment: @SwiftyJD I would ask another question (and accept mine ;)). I'm pretty sure you can't do that though.